# Design pattern for encrypting/decrypting object properties in Get/Set

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, getter-setter

I am trying to find a good design pattern that will allow me to store a users private information as encrypted cipher text yet make the encryption/decryption seamless to the user of the object.

For example ... lets say I have a Patient object and a property on the object is some private information such as Social Security Number (SSN). I want to store this in the database as an encrypted value yet allow application code to get/set the SSN using syntax such as ...

```
// Getting the unencrypted SSN
var currentSSN = selectedPatient.SSN;

// Setting the unencrypted SSN, but will be encrypted in Setter
selectedPatient.SSN = "555-55-5555";
```

I tried placing the encryption/decryption in the getter and setter as such ...

```
public string SSN
{
  get 
  {
    return MyEncryptionClass.Decrypt(this.SSN);
  }
  set
  {
    value =  MyEncryptionClass.Encrypt(value);
  }
}
```

*NOTE: Assume the Key and Initialization Vector are both handled by the Encrypt/Decrypt methods. I wanted to focus on the Get/Set portion.*

The problem is I find that the SSN is stored as plain text in the database record even though I have the Encrypt method in the Setter. I can confirm by debugging that the Encrypt routine is in fact returning proper cipher text, yet it does not seem to be stored in the database record as such. My thinking is that the Get/Set is somewhat circular. That by setting the value I am calling the decrypt method so what gets stored in the record is in fact decrypted.

Is there a pattern that people have found that works that allows this encryption/decryption to be seamless to the consumer of the object. I want to avoid them from having to manually call the encrypt/decrypt methods.

EDIT - I am using Entity Framework v6

Comment: The data access code is just another client of the object. When the data access code tries to read the value of the SSN property to store it in the database, it gets an unencrypted value as any other client would.

Comment: You might want to give us an idea of how you do data access. More specifically, how do you store data from the object into the database? Are you using entity framework?

Comment: That makes sense. Any suggestions on how to design a better pattern? I use Entity Framework 6 Code First for data access.

Comment: It should be `this.SSN =  MyEncryptionClass.Encrypt(value);`, no?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Thanks .. I will correct that in the example.

Comment: You can have two properties. One that is mapped to the real column in the database. This property is an normal auto property. The other property (marked to be ignored by EF) would simply invoke the other property and decrypt/encrypt as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple pattern could be the following:

```
// this property will be persisted in the database, but can't be modified from outside
public string SSN { get; private set; }

// the attribute will make sure this doesn't get mapped to the db
// this property uses the other property as a backing field with proper conversions
[NotMapped]
public string SSNDecrypted
{
  get 
  {
    return MyEncryptionClass.Decrypt(this.SSN);
  }
  set
  {
    this.SSN =  MyEncryptionClass.Encrypt(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering if anyone knows how to move the getter/setter actions to an attribute so that you don't have to write individual getter/setter for each property you want to encrypt.